# It is possible to create double cli commands in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I just finished [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js) about creating Node.js CLI. I learned how to create single CLI command with parameters, e. g. `my-cli-command --parameter`.

What if my CLI must to do multiple things? Off course, we could pass target action as parameter:

```
my-cli --doSomething1
my-cli --doSomething2
```

But in this case,

```
my-cli doSomething1 --otherParameter
my-cli doSomething2 --otherParameter
```

well be more elegant. It it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below listing is from same tutorial. `args._` array (always exists but could be empty) contains all subcommands.

```
import arg from 'arg';

function parseArgumentsIntoOptions(rawArgs) {
 const args = arg(
   {
     '--git': Boolean,
     '--yes': Boolean,
     '--install': Boolean,
     '-g': '--git',
     '-y': '--yes',
     '-i': '--install',
   },
   {
     argv: rawArgs.slice(2),
   }
 );
 return {
   skipPrompts: args['--yes'] || false,
   git: args['--git'] || false,
   template: args._[0],
   runInstall: args['--install'] || false,
 };
}
```